# Randomise upload filenames (or another solution to hide the original image URL from theft?)

Tags: php, functions, hooks, uploads, scale

Our users upload high resolution artwork that we need to protect from theft. The images are resized and watermarked, but it's still trivial for somebody to guess the original URL and gain access to the full resolution image.

I'm trying to figure out a solution, the easiest (I think?) being to randomise the filenames. I can randomise filenames on upload using something like:

```php
function randomize_uploaded_filename( $filename ) {
    // Do things...
    return $filename
}
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'randomize_uploaded_filename', 10 );
```

however this will change the filename **before** wordpress scales the images. No good.

I can also rename the scaled sizes as they are generated so that they each have a unique random filename (used in conjunction with the above this would mean that all image files can have unguessable filenames, right? almost....):

```php
add_filter( 'image_make_intermediate_size', 'rename_intermediates' );
function rename_intermediates( $image ) {
    $info = pathinfo($image);
    $dir = $info['dirname'] . '/';
    $ext = '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = wp_basename( $image, "$ext" );

    $randomString = '' // random stuff here

    // Build our new image name
    $new_name = $dir . $randomString . $ext;

    // Rename the intermediate size
    $did_it = rename( $image, $new_name );

    // Renaming successful, return new name
    if( $did_it )
        return $new_name;

    return $image;
}
```

**But**, if I do this, wordpress doesn't remember the new filenames. So if the original file is uploaded and saved as, say, *painting.jpg* , and the scaled versions have some randomised filenames like *jkn4jk53u567u.jpg* , wordpress will still think that the scaled version is called *painting-scaled.jpg* , etc. Resulting in broken images.

Where am I going wrong? I really appreciate the help :-)

**Edit -** Here's the second portion in full as per @SallyCJ 's request:

```php
add_filter( 'image_make_intermediate_size', 'rename_intermediates' );
function rename_intermediates( $image ) {
    // Split the $image path into directory/extension/name
    $info = pathinfo($image);
    $dir = $info['dirname'] . '/';
    $ext = '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = wp_basename( $image, "$ext" );

    // Generate a random alphanumeric string
    $randcharacters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $randcharactersLength = strlen($randcharacters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $randcharacters[rand(0, $randcharactersLength - 1)];
    }
    
    // Build our new image name
    $new_name = $dir . $randomString . '-' . $name . $ext;

    // Rename the intermediate size
    $did_it = rename( $image, $new_name );

    // Renaming successful, return new name
    if( $did_it )
        return $new_name;

    return $image;
}
```

**Edit 27th Feb 2021 in response to Sally CJ's answer:**

I apologise for my slow reply, it has been a busy few days! Firstly, thank you for your incredibly educational and detailed response! :O

Your fix is fantastic but not quite working fully for me, I'll explain. When I upload `picture.jpg` it generates everything as you've said, and Wordpress can now correctly see the location of the original AND scaled image (e.g. `768O4Y7q-picture-scaled.jpg`). Brilliant! It can't see all the smaller sizes, though. On the Media Library (upload.php) page it thinks the smaller size `BFcUGvP8-picture-100x100.jpg` image used as the thumbnail is called `picture-100x100.jpg`. However, in other areas it can see other various renamed smaller sizes sizes just fine...

I've also noticed that when regenerating smaller sizes it adds another 8 random characters to the start of the filename each time (based off the "new" original filename), and **it doesn't delete the old smaller sizes during regeneration**. It saves new ones alongside the old ones. Ouch! That's a big problem that'll cause exploding disk space use haha.

This is touched upon briefly on the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` reference page:

> "This function can be used to regenerate thumbnail and intermediate sizes of the image [...] but it does not check or delete intermediate sizes it previously created for the same image."

There are a few other big issues with the image regeneration, too.

At this point the issues that remain are:

**1.** The new smaller size locations aren't all being updated, leading to some broken smaller size images (could it be custom image sizes causing the issue? Is 100x100 a custom size?)

**2.** Image regeneration doesn't delete the old generated smaller sizes.

**3.** Image regeneration seems to re-check the "original" file's filename and draw from that, which reveals the random string at the start that "hides" it. Also, it prepends the original file with *another* set of random characters, e.g. `JGcYJrP9-picture.jpg` would become `H7liJRPW-JGcYJrP9-picture.jpg`, and the new smaller image sizes would be named things like `vWCdtas2-JGcYJrP9-picture-100x100.jpg`. After another round of regeneration that file would become say, `2jLL72he-H7liJRPW-JGcYJrP9-picture-100x100.jpg`, etc.

**4.** I would like to truncate the uploaded filenames to 50 characters max. I don't think I mentioned this previously, I was going to do it myself with `substr($whatever, 0, 50)` but I'm having trouble (it works fine for the original and -scaled images but when I try it on the smaller sizes, it doesn't update their new filenames properly any more).

May I trouble you to help for a little longer? - By the way I don't know if this is frowned upon here but as you have been patient with me and your answers have been extremely detailed, do you per chance have a buymeacoffee.com or similar? You really deserve it!

Frankly, I don't need to put random characters at the start of the scaled versions - I really only need them on the original to ensure nobody can ever guess the URL. So I don't need to get that working perfectly. I *do* need to get those regeneration bugs ironed out though :( And I'd really love to be able to restrict the filename length.... users write whole novels in their filenames! >_<

Comment: Your code looks good to me, so are you sure that you're getting broken images? What code did you try when displaying the image? Could it be a caching issue (did you try clearing the site and your browser caches)?

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm using the normal WP Media library for this whole process. Using the latter method above to rename the scaled sizes, if I upload an image the scaled sizes are generated and named randomly e.g.:

`5p1qntwy.jpg`
`1stykqpwq.jpg`
..etc,

and the original filename has the randomly generated characters inserted at the start, e.g.:
`b90a5NUv-IMG_9813.jpg`

WP gets the original file URL right, but gets the scaled image sizes wrong. It thinks the main scaled image is e.g.:
`b90a5NUv-IMG_9813-scaled.jpg`

But, the main scaled image is actually called `5p1qntwy.jpg`.

Comment: Are you actually using both the first (`sanitize_file_name`) and second (`image_make_intermediate_size`) filters? You should use just the second - try removing the first and see if the issue persists? And do you also want to randomize the name of the *original* image?

Comment: First off - I really appreciate your trying to help me out :-) Unfortunately just using the second filter on its own has the same problem. It successfully renames all the scaled images, but Wordpress has no idea what those filenames are - it blindly thinks they're the regular filenames that it would normally generate. I'm guessing I need to figure out how to adjust how Wordpress stores these filenames in its database when it generates them, so it remembers the correct modified filenames for all the sizes? That's currently a bit beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Just doing some research - Wordpress stores attachments as posts with the `post_type` of `attachment`, and the full URL of the original image is stored in `guid`. I don't see any information about how it stores the location of the scaled images though, I'm worried that perhaps it doesn't - and perhaps it always relies on extrapolating from the original image URL? If this is the case, I'm truly at a loss as to how I can ensure the URL of the original image is not guessable by the public & thus stealable :-(

Comment: Yes, the original image is stored as an attachment post, and yes, its `guid` normally contains the URL of the original image file. But as for the scaled images, their details are saved in a [metadata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/). And actually, I already tested your second code and it worked fine for me (i.e. no broken images), so how did you generate the random string? Can you show the actual part/code which fills the `$randomString` variable?

Comment: I've added the full thing to my original post @SallyCJ

Comment: Thanks for the code and sorry! I think I didn't really pay attention to the "-scaled" version of the original (high-res) image.. I mean, you're right - and why the issue happens is because the scaled version also gets renamed, but it's a special entry in which WordPress updates its (meta)data *before* the intermediate sizes are created, but WordPress no longer updates the data afterwards even if the scaled version got a new path/name/etc. Therefore WordPress still using the old file name having "-scaled", e.g. `/some/path/some-name-scaled.jpg`.

Comment: And just so you know, advanced users could easily check the REST API on your site (e.g. the default media/attachment endpoint at `example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media`) and the original file names will be exposed by default (and I'm not referring to just the `guid`, but other fields like `original_image`). So instead of randomizing the file names, perhaps you can try looking for [or using another option](https://kinsta.com/blog/protect-images/)?..

Comment: I think I have the REST API locked down, though I'm not deeply familiar so please correct me if I'm wrong. When I load up something like `/wp-json/wp/v2/media`, `/wp-json/wp/v2/media?search=file.jpg`, even as an admin, I'm greeted by `{"code":"itsec_rest_api_access_restricted","message":"You do not have sufficient permission to access this endpoint. Access to REST API requests is restricted by iThemes Security settings.","data":{"status":401}}`. Hmm... all I need to do at the end of the day is have the original filename be un-guessable. Can accomplish this? Or I must find another solution? :-(

Comment: So did my answer help? Did the code work? If so, I'd appreciate it if you can mark my answer as correct (just tick the check-mark next to my answer) - doing so will help others know the question has an accepted solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Where am I going wrong?

Actually, your code is just fine.

Except that I would simply use [`wp_generate_password()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/) to generate the random string. :)

> WordPress will still think that the scaled version is called
> *painting-scaled.jpg* , etc. Resulting in broken images.

Yes, that's correct.

Images are stored as posts of the `attachment` type in the WordPress posts table (in the database), and the details (width, height, full file path, etc.) of the main image and its intermediate sizes (e.g. thumbnail and medium) are stored in a (private) meta named `_wp_attachment_metadata` — see [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/) and [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/) for more info, but the meta value basically consists of:

- **'width'**
  *(int)*  The width of the attachment.
- **'height'**
  *(int)*  The height of the attachment.
- **'file'**
  *(string)*  The file path relative to  `wp-content/uploads`.
- **'sizes'**
  *(array)*  Keys are size slugs, each value is an array containing 'file', 'width', 'height', and 'mime-type'.
- **'image_meta'**
  *(array)*  Image metadata.

And as for the [-scaled version](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/10/09/introducing-handling-of-big-images-in-wordpress-5-3/), if available, it will be used with the `file` item above and there'll be an additional item named `original_image` added to the above meta where the item's value will be the path to the originally uploaded image file — see [`wp_get_original_image_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_original_image_path/).

So because the `image_make_intermediate_size` filters are applied both when generating the -scaled version and the intermediate sizes, then the -scaled version also gets renamed by your custom filter (the `rename_intermediates()` function), but unlike the above `sizes` item, WordPress no longer updates the `file` item once it is set after the -scaled version is generated.

Therefore that resulted in the broken image for the -scaled version.

### But don't fret, there's a solution.

Yes, and basically you just need to use a different hook: [`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_generate_attachment_metadata/).

So just remove your `image_make_intermediate_size` filter and use the code below, and just let me know if you need any clarification:

```php
// *UPDATED Feb 27th 2021 UTC

// Renames a file and if it succeeded, returns an array with the first item being the new name
// (e.g. <random string>-my-image.jpg). And this function is intended to be used only with the
// my_rename_images() below.
function my_rename_image( $file, $_rand_str = '' ) {
    $info = pathinfo( $file );

    $rand_str = wp_generate_password( 8, false ); // false = do not use special chars
    $new_name = $rand_str . '-' . ( $_rand_str ?
        str_replace( "{$_rand_str}-", '', $info['basename'] ) : $info['basename'] );
    $new_file = $info['dirname'] . '/' . $new_name;

    return rename( $file, $new_file ) ? array( $new_name, $rand_str ) : false;
}

// Note: The _main_rand_str meta is used to prevent re-adding the random string to the name of
// the renamed image files.
add_filter( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'my_rename_images', 10, 3 );
function my_rename_images( $metadata, $attachment_id, $context ) {
    // Do nothing if the attachment is NOT an image, or if the attachment wasn't being
    // created.
    if ( 'create' !== $context || empty( $metadata['image_meta'] ) ) {
        return $metadata;
    }

    $file = get_attached_file( $attachment_id );
    $_rand_str = get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_main_rand_str', true );

    if ( $arr = my_rename_image( $file, $_rand_str ) ) {
        $metadata['file'] = dirname( $metadata['file'] ) . '/' . $arr[0];
        update_attached_file( $attachment_id, $metadata['file'] );
        update_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_main_rand_str', $arr[1] );
    }

    $dir = dirname( $file );
    foreach ( $metadata['sizes'] as $size => $data ) {
        if ( $arr = my_rename_image( $dir . '/' . $data['file'], $_rand_str ) ) {
            $metadata['sizes'][ $size ]['file'] = $arr[0];
        }
    }

    if ( ! empty( $metadata['original_image'] ) ) {
        $file = $dir . '/' . $metadata['original_image'];
        if ( $arr = my_rename_image( $file, $_rand_str ) ) {
            $metadata['original_image'] = $arr[0];
            update_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_main_rand_str', $arr[1] );
        }
    }

    return $metadata;
}
```

#### Sample output

So I uploaded a hi-res JPEG image via the Media → Add New admin page, and the generated file names/sizes are:

```
| File Name                             | Size Name      | Note                    | 
|---------------------------------------|----------------|-------------------------| 
| 768O4Y7q-foo-bar-image-scaled.jpg     |                | The "-scaled" version   | 
| zDQdlxMK-foo-bar-image-300x200.jpg    | medium         |                         | 
| 6CT8XZGI-foo-bar-image-1024x683.jpg   | large          |                         | 
| BFcUGvP8-foo-bar-image-150x150.jpg    | thumbnail      |                         | 
| 2vATG8xN-foo-bar-image-768x512.jpg    | medium_large   |                         | 
| 8xjeou4f-foo-bar-image-1536x1024.jpg  | 1536x1536      |                         | 
| 59YJJsQF-foo-bar-image-2048x1366.jpg  | 2048x2048      |                         | 
| 6HjAlOnr-foo-bar-image-1568x1046.jpg  | post-thumbnail |                         | 
| XQTkPM7I-foo-bar-image.jpg            |                | Original, but renamed   |
```

### UPDATE

In response to "**Edit 27th Feb 2021**" in the question:

1. "*The new smaller size locations aren't all being updated*" — this didn't seem to have happened in my case, so please try the updated code *above* and see if the issue persists.
2. "*Image regeneration doesn't delete the old generated smaller sizes.*" — yes, because as you quoted it yourself, WordPress core says, "*it **does not** check or delete intermediate sizes it previously created for the same image*".

   So I'm afraid you'll need to either manually delete the existing intermediate sizes, or find a plugin which can help you delete them. But note that one good reason why WordPress doesn't delete the intermediate sizes, is because those images might be in use in that they were linked to from somewhere (which is not a thief..), so simply deleting the images is not a good idea.
3. Sorry about the random string which got re-added to the name of the renamed files.. But I've corrected it in the updated code *above*.

Comment: I'm sorry for the slow response! - I have written a hopefully detailed enough reply after trying this out and banging my head against it for a few hours, see my original question under **Edit 27th Feb 2021 in response to Sally CJ's answer** 

Comment: Please check the "UPDATE" part in my answer, but as for the "*I would like to truncate the uploaded filenames to 50 characters max.*", I'd love to help you with that, but can you ask that in a separate question later on? Because that wasn't part of the original question, so for new questions or further code customizations, you should post them each as a new question. That's how things work on this site. :)